# How to find distinct dates across multiple tables / columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, date, union

I have a project planner app. Part of the app shows the project's timeline.
There are three tables that hold the timeline info; Stage_Plan, Target_Date, Actual_Date.

I want to be able to list all the dates that a change has been made to the project timeline.

All three tables have "Created_DateTime" & "Deleted_Datetime" (If a user deletes a stage or edits a Target_Date then "Is_Deleted" is set to true and that stage/old date is hidden from view).

So I want to get all distinct cases of these two dates across the three tables.

Is the best/only way to do this to do 6 select statements and union the results together?

i.e

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(Created_DateTime AS Date)  
FROM stg.Stage_Plan 

UNION 

SELECT DISTINCT CAST(Deleted_DateTime AS Date) 
FROM stg.Stage_Plan 

UNION 

SELECT DISTINCT CAST(AD.Created_DateTime AS Date) 
FROM stg.Stage_Plan SP 
     JOIN stg.Stage_Plan_Actual_Date AD ON SP.Stage_Plan_ID = AD.Stage_Plan_ID

UNION 

SELECT DISTINCT CAST(AD.Deleted_DateTime AS Date) 
FROM stg.Stage_Plan SP 
     JOIN stg.Stage_Plan_Actual_Date AD ON SP.Stage_Plan_ID = AD.Stage_Plan_ID 

UNION 

SELECT DISTINCT CAST(TD.Deleted_DateTime AS Date) 
FROM stg.Stage_Plan SP 
     JOIN stg.Stage_Plan_Target_Date TD ON SP.Stage_Plan_ID = TD.Stage_Plan_ID

UNION 

SELECT DISTINCT CAST(TD.Created_DateTime AS Date) 
FROM stg.Stage_Plan SP 
     JOIN stg.Stage_Plan_Target_Date TD ON SP.Stage_Plan_ID = TD.Stage_Plan_ID
```

This just seems very ugly.
(I know the DISTINCT is irrelevant because I am doing a UNION)

Wanted output is a list all the dates that a change has been made to the project timeline e.g:

```
2020-05-29
2020-06-01
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: No, I dont think there is a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cross apply`. I think that the following query does what you want:

```
select distinct x.dt 
from stg.Stage_Plan sp
left join stg.stage_plan_actual_date ad on sp.stage_plan_id = ad.stage_plan_id
left join stg.stage_plan_target_date td on sp.stage_plan_id = td.stage_plan_id
cross apply (values
    (sp.Created_DateTime), (sp.Deleted_DateTime), 
    (ad.Created_DateTime), (ad.Deleted_DateTime), 
    (td.Created_DateTime), (td.Deleted_DateTime) 
) x(dt)
where sp.stage_plan_id = ?
```

Presumably you want data for a given project, if so you should also have a `where` clause in the query - I added that.

Comment: Great - thanks for that. I have never heard of cross apply before.